# Scrapy crawl command not scraping correctly

Tags: python, scrapy

ive launched a scrapy project and created this crawler:

```
import scrapy

class CarSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'Car_Scrape'
    page_number = 2

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.finn.no/car/used/search.html?orgId=9117269&page=1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for quote in response.css('article.ads__unit'):

            yield {
                'title': quote.css('a.ads__unit__link::text').get(),
                'img:url': quote.css('img.img-format__img::attr(src)').get(),
                'link': quote.css('a.ads__unit__link::attr(href)').get(),
                'model_year': int(quote.css('div.ads__unit__content__keys div:nth-child(1)::text').get()),
                'mileage': int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, quote.css('div.ads__unit__content__keys div:nth-child(2)::text').get())))),
                'price':  int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, quote.css('div.ads__unit__content__keys div:nth-child(3)::text').get())))),
            }
```

The problem is when i try to run the crawl command:

```
scrapy crawl Car_Scrape -o data.json
```

It only scraped the 23 first cars. But when i run this command in the scrapy shell for the same url:

```
for quote in response.css('article.ads__unit'):
     print(quote.css('a.ads__unit__link::text').get())
```

I get the whole page scraped. I want the same result achived in the CarSpider class. Is there anything im doing wrong? If someone could check if they get the same problem, or mabye my project is bugging. Any help is grealy appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

If I try running your spider, I get 26 items, but then it throws an error:

```
2020-10-04 19:52:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.finn.no/car/used/search.html?orgId=9117269&page=1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\Users\Ivan\Documents\Python\a.py", line 22, in parse
    'price':  int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, quote.css('div.ads__unit__content__keys div:nth-child(3)::text').get())))),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Looking at the page, the problematic listing has `Solgt` where you expected a price, which your code doesn't handle correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry i didnt update the question. I just used a try except while loop for if the item im webscraping is not an integer. So if the data i get is not an integer i change the price to a string "Solgt"